# Joining reference tables to a table other than the base table

Tags: mysql

Basically I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT MAIN.response_id AS 'Response Id', 
    CONCAT(CASE 
        WHEN MAIN.months = 'Jan - Mar' THEN 'March'
        WHEN MAIN.months = 'Apr - Jun' THEN 'June'
        WHEN MAIN.months = 'Jul - Sep' THEN 'September'
        WHEN MAIN.months = 'Oct - Dec' THEN 'December'
        ELSE 'Error'
    END, ' ', MAIN.Year) AS Period,
    CNT.country_name AS Country, INITM.num_modules AS 'Initial Training - Number of Modules', INITTRAINED.num_instr AS 'Initial Training - Instructors Trained', INITPASS.pass_num AS 'Initial Training - Instructors Passed', INITPASS.pass_num / INITTRAINED.num_instr AS 'Initial Training - Pass Percentage'
FROM responses_main AS MAIN -- Main responses table
LEFT OUTER JOIN responses_init_training_modules AS INITM USING (response_id) -- Main INIT training table
LEFT OUTER JOIN responses_init_training_pass_num AS INITPASS USING (response_id) -- Main INIT training table
LEFT OUTER JOIN responses_init_training_instr_trained AS INITTRAINED USING (response_id) -- Main INIT training table
LEFT OUTER JOIN country AS CNT ON MAIN.country_id = CNT.country_id -- Country table
GROUP BY MAIN.response_id, MAIN.months + ' ' + MAIN.Year, CNT.country_name
```

What is missing from this query is a join to the program table. Each of the referenced tables (INITM, INITPASS and INITTRAINED) have a program_id which references the program table however the base table (MAIN) is not related to the program table. The current query results in a table returning only data for the first program_id + doesn't show any program information.

How can I derive a data set showing MAIN.response_id, PROG.program_id, INITM.num_modules, INITPASS.pass_num and INITTRAINED.instr_trained? I can't figure out how to get a table referencing both dimensions (MAIN and PROG) with data from the 3 referenced tables.

I have drawn out what I am trying to achieve here:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Don't draw it out. Sqlfiddle it.

Comment: You wrote that 3 of your tables have program_id as a foreign key. Which of these 3 tables should reference the program table?

Comment: @shadow its the responses_init_training_modules, responses_init_training_pass_num and responses_init_training_instr_trained tables. The responses_main table has no program_id column.

Comment: You misunderstood me. Any of these 3 tables can be used in the query to reference the program table. Which one should be used?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your data structure is causing the difficulties.. I'm assuming your 3 `responses_init_*` are subclasses of `responses_main`.

Assuming one response only applies to one program, I would probably approach this by moving all the `program_id` columns to the `responses_main` table and go from there:

```
    SELECT ...
      FROM program p
      JOIN responses_main rm
        ON rm.program_id = p.program_id 
 LEFT JOIN responses_init_training_modules ritm
        ON ritm.response_id = rm.response_id 
 LEFT JOIN responses_init_training_pass_num ritpn
        ON ritpn.response_id = rm.response_id 
 LEFT JOIN responses_init_training_instr_trained ritit
        ON ritit.response_id = rm.response_id
       ...
```

Notes:

- I'd decide between single and plural for table names (`responses`, `program`)
- If you are using quarters save it as a `TINYINT` or store the start and end of the range as an `TINYINT` for month or `DATE` separately. Storing any kind of range as a hyphen separated string will give you issues later on.

**UPDATE**

Talk to your DBA, explain what you need and see if he'll change it for you and it makes sense.

In the mean time, either run the three joins to program separately:

```
LEFT JOIN program ritmp
       ON ritmp.program_id = ritm.program_id
LEFT JOIN program ritpnp
       ON ritpnp.program_id = ritpn.program_id
LEFT JOIN program rititp
       ON rititp.program_id = ritit.program_id
```

Or you could use:

```
(LEFT) JOIN program p ON p.program_id = COALESCE(ritm.program_id, ritpn.program_id, ritit.program_id)
```

But it'll be slow and I would recommend it as a last resort.

Comment: Hi there, I appreciate the response. Unfortunately the responses_main table has no link to the program table on its own. It links to the sub tables as does the program table. Any ideas? Also, completely agree with your thoughts on the design, unfortunately this is handled by someone else - I just report from it.